# foreignobject or object Tag in stacked svg not registering click in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm having difficulties regarding a button in an SVG that is embedded in an SVG.
This weird configuration is used as I am simulating a physical device,
don't need responsiveness and separating code for different parts in respective SVGs reduced complexity.

This worked great on Chrome and Firefox but in Safari the clicks aren't registering even though the object is found, and an event listener is attached.

Because I am able to call the alert from main.svg even when the website is embedded into HTML via object tag, I concluded that the object tag cant be responsible.

This is a very simplified version of my problem.
I want to call the alert on second.svg when clicking the green rectangle. The alert on the pink area works as it is on main.svg.

**main.svg:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="1920" height="1080" viewBox="0 0 508 285.75" version="1.1" id="svg5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <rect style="fill:#ff9393;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:0.283084;stroke-miterlimit:10;fill-opacity:1" id="rect1048" width="508" height="285.75" x="0" y="0" />
    <foreignObject width="190.6078" height="244.0815" x="26.305603" y="22.424448" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <xhtml:body>
        <xhtml:object
           width="100%"
           type="image/svg+xml"
           data="/second.svg" />
      </xhtml:body>
    </foreignObject>
  </g>
  <script>
     document.getElementById("rect1048").addEventListener("click", () => {
      alert("this works on safari"); // this works in safari
     });
  </script>
</svg>
```

**second.svg:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="1920" height="1080" viewBox="0 0 508 285.75" version="1.1" id="svg5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <rect style="fill:#008000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:0.283084;stroke-miterlimit:10;fill-opacity:1" id="rect1048" width="508" height="285.75" x="0" y="0" />
  </g>
  <script>
     document.getElementById("rect1048").addEventListener("click", () => {
      alert("this message is what I want called from here if possible"); // this doesnt work in safari
     });
  </script>
</svg>
```

Any help or any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Also if there is any clarification needed please go ahead and ask.
I am still new to programming and this platform.

Comment: you can report webkit bugs [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/)

Comment: @RobertLongson
I was still thinking think I am missing something.
Do you belive this is a Bug?
I have no clue but it seems to be inconsistent with Chrome and Firefox at least.
Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you change the attribute name from "href" to "src" in the script tag: `<script type="text/ecmascript" href="button.js" id="script5255" />`. I guess the element/attribute will just be ignored, but still... And remove the `<defs>` if it does not have content,

Comment: @chrwahl
Unfortunately, no. the code (including the inner one) is executed but still does not work. I emptied button.js and forgot to remove it. i packed the content directly into the script tags to shorten the length of the question.
Still a good idea. I tried that too.